# Integrating selenium with 2captcha to solve Recapv2

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, recaptcha

I'm trying to make a script that autofills info for a specific form, I created that and it autofills fine but when I the script clicks on the enter button a captcha pops up, I decided to take the 2captcha route rather then the audio captcha bypass. I found a package that simplifies the 2cap API down for you(https://pypi.org/project/2captcha-python/#recaptcha-v2). I can send a request to 2captcha and they solve the captcha, I know this because my daily stats go up 1 everytime I run the script, but nothing happens on the selenium browser. Any reason?

current code is

```
    solver = TwoCaptcha('MYAPIKEY')

    config = {
                'apiKey':           'MYAPIKEY',
                'softId':            123,
                'callback':         'https://your.site/result-receiver',
                'defaultTimeout':    120,
                'recaptchaTimeout':  600,
                'pollingInterval':   10,
            }
    solver = TwoCaptcha(**config)

result = solver.recaptcha(sitekey='6Le-wvkSVVABCPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq1bi0DJwx_mJ-',
                          url="https://mailchi.mp/2d4364715d21/b66a2p7spo",)
```

I run this inside of a try: except: with the autofill code in it after It clicks enter(when the captcha pops up) any one have any ideas on how I can solve this? I've been trying for a couple hours and I can't figure it out.

Note: I left softId and callback as the default values because I don't have a softId from 2cap and I don't have a website either, if that's the issue please advise on how I can go about solving it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api

Comment: Hey, I took a look at that and I'm still having issues sending the captcha ID from 2cap to the website. Any ideas?